# Unity - Particle system - Particle count

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particles

Does any know if Unity has a way to count how many particles have been emitted by a particle system?  So I could check to see if there has been an emission, like:

```
public ParticleSystem mySystem;
private int currentParticleCount;
private int lastParticleCount;

void Start () {
    lastParticleCount = mySystem.getEmissionCount();
}

void Update () {
    currentParticleCount = mySystem.getEmissionCount();
    if(currentParticleCount>lastParticleCount) {
        DoStuff();
    }
    lastParticleCount = currentParticleCount;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ParticleSystem.particleCount`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem-particleCount.html) to return the current number of particles. If that's not giving you the proper amount of particles, use the [`ParticleSystem.GetParticles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.GetParticles.html) function since that returns just the current number of *alive* particles. Below is an example for both of them:

```
private ParticleSystem ps;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    ps = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Debug.Log("Particles Count: " + ps.particleCount);
    Debug.Log("Particles Alive Count: " + GetAliveParticles());
}

int GetAliveParticles()
{
    ParticleSystem.Particle[] particles = new ParticleSystem.Particle[ps.particleCount];
    return ps.GetParticles(particles);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact feature that you are asking for is not build it, BUT:

You can know the current particles displayed by the system, so you can make a counter that acumulates the number, or if you know the "displaying time" you can do the maths.

Knowing the current particles: 
`ParticleSystem.particleCount` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem-particleCount.html